# Iterate indexed list with sed for python SLURM script

Tags: python, bash, sed, slurm, hpc

My goal is to iterate two indexed lists of **start_times** and **output_directories**, using ***sed*** to change the start time within *runConfig.sh* and the output directory within *HISTORY.rc* before each job submission (*36 in total*).

The script is written in python and uses *os.system()* to deploy *linux bash* commands, see below:

```
##-> Key Module Import(s)
import os

##-> Primary Workspace
#->  Create GCHP output directories for each run accordingly to their respective starting date
Root_Path = '/home/jaljbour/GCHP_NEW/ExtData/clean_run_C24_TT/OutputDir/'
Dir_List = ['Start_01_2017', 'Start_02_2017', 'Start_03_2017', 'Start_04_2017', 'Start_05_2017', 'Start_06_2017', 'Start_07_2017', 'Start_08_2017', 'Start_09_2017', 'Start_10_2017', 'Start_11_2017', 'Start_12_2017',
        'Start_01_2018', 'Start_02_2018', 'Start_03_2018', 'Start_04_2018', 'Start_05_2018', 'Start_06_2018', 'Start_07_2018', 'Start_08_2018', 'Start_09_2018', 'Start_10_2018', 'Start_11_2018', 'Start_12_2018',
        'Start_01_2019', 'Start_02_2019', 'Start_03_2019', 'Start_04_2019', 'Start_05_2019', 'Start_06_2019', 'Start_07_2019', 'Start_08_2019', 'Start_09_2019', 'Start_10_2019', 'Start_11_2019', 'Start_12_2019']

for items in Dir_List:
    path = os.path.join(Root_Path, items)
    os.mkdir(path)

#->  Set number of jobs to be submitted, point to respective directories, and loop 'sed' edits of the runConfig.sh for each respective run
Num_Jobs = 36

StrTi_List = ['20170101 000000', '20170201 000000', '20170301 000000', '20170401 000000', '20170501 000000', '20170601 000000', '20170701 000000', '20170801 000000', '20170901 000000', '20171001 000000', '20171101 000000', '20171201 000000',
           '20180101 000000', '20180201 000000', '20180301 000000', '20180401 000000', '20180501 000000', '20180601 000000', '20180701 000000', '20180801 000000', '20180901 000000', '20181001 000000', '20181101 000000', '20181201 000000',
           '20190101 000000', '20190201 000000', '20190301 000000', '20190401 000000', '20190501 000000', '20190601 000000', '20190701 000000', '20190801 000000', '20190901 000000', '20191001 000000', '20191101 000000', '20191201 000000',]

for j in range(0, Num_Jobs):
    sed_1 = 'sed -i "s|Start_Time\=.*|Start_Time\=\"${StrTi_List[j]}\"|" ./runConfig.sh'       # Edit start month in runConfig.sh
    os.system(sed_1)
    sed_2 = 'sed -i "s|EXPID\:.*|EXPID\:\"${Dir_List[j]}\"|" ./HISTORY.rc'                     # Edit output directory in HISTORY.rc
    os.system(sed_2)
    os.system('#SBATCH gchp.runscript')                                                        # Submit array of jobs
```

The first loop successfully creates the output_directories, but the second loops fails to both edit the target files and submit the 36 jobs. (*Both files have their original contents removed in the target code lines, but instead display blank lines*)

Thank you in advance and I look forward to getting this resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Your variable interpolation is `bash` syntax, not `python`'s one.
Would you please try instead:

```
sed_1 = f"sed -i 's|Start_Time=.*|Start_Time=\"{StrTi_List[j]}\"|' ./runConfig.sh"
sed_2 = f"sed -i 's|EXPID:.*|EXPID:\"{Dir_List[j]}\"|' ./HISTORY.rc"
```

If your `python` is older than `3.6`, here are the alternatives:

```
sed_1 = "sed -i 's|Start_Time=.*|Start_Time=\"%s\"|' ./runConfig.sh" % StrTi_List[j]
sed_2 = "sed -i 's|EXPID:.*|EXPID:\"%s\"|' ./HISTORY.rc" % Dir_List[j]
```

As I'm not aware of your actual lines in `runConfig.sh` and `HISTORY.rc`,
some modifications in the replacement may be needed. Please let me know then.